# Add punctuation to string in c++

Tags: c++, mingw

I am making a function that adds punctuation to a string if the string has none. I think I have done everything correctly and the program compiles fine but no matter what I set the string to, an extra punctuation is always added.

source code:

```
// Word Parsing
if(
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "." || 
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "?" || 
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "!"
) {
    cout << str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) << endl;
    str_input = str_input+".";
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your code by assigning the last character in a string to a temporary character variable.  This temporary character would be compared to ".", "?" and "!".

Comment: should the || be && instead, !="." && !="?" && !="!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `||` with `&&`.

With your example, if your string ends with "?" it will be different from ".", and you will enter in your `if` statement.

You want to make sure that your character is different from "." **AND** "?" **AND** "!".

```
if(
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "." && 
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "?" && 
    str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1) != "!"
)
{
     // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code would be simpler is you used a "not any of these" logic:

```
char ending_char = str_input.substr(str_input.length()-1, 1);
if ( ! ((ending_char == '!') || (ending_char == '.') || (ending_char == '?")))
{
  cout << ending_char << endl;
  str_input += ending_char;
}
```